# NGinx Domain name redirects

Tags: redirect, dns, nginx

Lets say I have a website named xyz.co, I also have other domain names with the same prefix like xyz.com, xyz.it, xyz.co.it

Right now nginx works fine with server_name xyz.co in nginx.conf in port 80 I would want all the other domains to redirect to xyz.co also I would want www.* versions of the above to redirect to xyz.co. How can I get this? Is this nginx webserver level changes? or I need to make this changes in DNS?

**UPDATE:** I tried this in `nginx.conf` but no use...

```
server
{
listen 80;
server_name xyz.co xyz.com, xyz.it, xyz.co.it;
rewrite ^/(.*) http://xyz.co permanent;
}
```

I first tried posting this question in ServerFault but no response there - https://serverfault.com/questions/453472/nginx-domain-name-redirects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add one server block for all the domain names that need to be redirected. like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xyz.com, xyz.it, xyz.co.it;
    rewrite ^ http://xyz.co$request_uri permanent;
}
```

and another server block for the xyz.co domain:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xyz.co;

    #other settings
}
```

this way when you go to one of the domain names that need to be redirected nginx will simply redirect to xyz.co and move into the other server block where you can add all your settings (rootfolder, location blocks, etc)